# Combine {stringr} and mutate() to manipulate multiple columns at once in large dataset?

Tags: r, stringr, dplyr

**Reprex**

```
df <- tibble(name = c("Person_1","Person_2","Person_3"),
             `AxxBxx1:0` = c("1:04","2:02","0:1"),
             `AxxCxx5:0` = c("5:04","3:02","0:0"),
             `BxxCxx2:1` = c("2:14","1:03","0:1"))
```

The goal is to transform this data.frame into another one, where the variables ending in `_real` are taken from the column names, and `_bet` and `_result` come from the first and second parts of `df`'s variable values:

```
df_2 <- tibble(name = c("Person_1","Person_2","Person_3"),
               AxxBxx_real = "1:0",
               AxxCxx_real = "5:0",
               BxxCxx_real = "2:1",
               AxxBxx_bet = c("1:0","2:0","0:1"),
               AxxCxx_bet = c("5:0","3:0","0:0"),
               BxxCxx_bet = c("2:1","1:0","0:1"),
               AxxBxx_result = c("4","2",""),
               AxxCxx_result = c("4","2",""),
               BxxCxx_result = c("4","3",""))
```

**Problem:** The real dataset is much larger than `df` and ideally I would like to automate that transformation of `df` to `df_2` as much as possible.

**Code (i.e., what I have done so far)**

```
library(tidyverse)

# Step 1: Get real match results from variable names.
df$AxxBxx_real <- "1:0"
df$AxxCxx_real <- "5:0"
df$BxxCxx_real <- "2:1"
```

Is there a way to `mutate()` the original variables from `df` into these three `_real` variables all at once, without looking up the individual match results? `mutate(names(df)[2:4] = str_extract(...))` or things like that obviously don't work.

```
# Create `_bet` and `_result` variables.
str_remove(names(df)[2:4], "[0-99]:[0-99]") %>%
  paste0("_bet") -> names(df)[2:4]

df %>%
  mutate(AxxBxx_result = AxxBxx_bet,
         AxxCxx_result = AxxCxx_bet,
         BxxCxx_result = BxxCxx_bet) -> df

df$AxxBxx_bet <- str_extract(df$AxxBxx_bet, "[0-99]:[0-99]")
df$AxxCxx_bet <- str_extract(df$AxxCxx_bet, "[0-99]:[0-99]")
df$BxxCxx_bet <- str_extract(df$BxxCxx_bet, "[0-99]:[0-99]")

df$AxxBxx_result <- str_remove(df$AxxBxx_result, "[0-99]:[0-99]")
df$AxxCxx_result <- str_remove(df$AxxCxx_result, "[0-99]:[0-99]")
df$BxxCxx_result <- str_remove(df$BxxCxx_result, "[0-99]:[0-99]")
```

Problem here is that although the process by which the bet is split from the result each person in the data.frame gets for his or her bet is somewhat standardized, the ways by which the new variables are created and stored is not. Instead of doing this for each variable separately, I would like to have this done somewhat automatically. Take original variables' names and remove result from their names, afterwards split into `_bet` and `_real`. Again, the issue is that I can only `mutate()` any given variable at a time. Is there a nicer, less time-consuming way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do this with `tidyr` library :

This gets the data in long format separating the column name in two parts, using `extract` we divide the values in two columns and finally get the data back in wide format.

I would suggest you to run this one step at a time to understand what's going on here.

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -name, 
               names_to = c('col1', 'real'), 
               names_pattern = '([A-Za-z]+)(\\d+:\\d+)') %>%
  extract(value, c('bet', 'result'), '(\\d+:.)(.)?') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col1, values_from = c(real, bet, result), 
              names_glue = '{col1}_{.value}')

#  name     AxxBxx_real AxxCxx_real BxxCxx_real AxxBxx_bet AxxCxx_bet BxxCxx_bet AxxBxx_result AxxCxx_result BxxCxx_result
#  <chr>    <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>         <chr>         <chr>        
#1 Person_1 1:0         5:0         2:1         1:0        5:0        2:1        "4"           "4"           "4"          
#2 Person_2 1:0         5:0         2:1         2:0        3:0        1:0        "2"           "2"           "3"          
#3 Person_3 1:0         5:0         2:1         0:1        0:0        0:1        ""            ""            ""
```

I am not sure why `name` changes from `Person_1`, `Person_2`, `Person_3` in input to `A`, `B` and `C` in output. I have kept name the same here.

Comment: Thank you, I was already considering to pivot it to long format, and extract, glue, etc. is what I needed.

Comment: Also, I fixed this A,B,C issue in the question.